# Close a popup view when tapping anywhere outside it, including buttons, textfields, etc

Tags: swift, popup, uitapgesturerecognizer

**Question EDITED** since it seems people were confused...

See my code below and watch the attached "video" of what is happening. The popup closes:

- when the user taps on a button selection within the popup
- when the user taps outside the popup, anywhere on the **parent** view (thus closing the popup without making a selection from the popup)

This is the behavior I want. BUT the popup does NOT close if the user taps on a button or textfield in the **parent** view. Consequently, the popup remains popped up in that situation.

How do I detect a tap gesture anywhere OUTSIDE the popup, including buttons, textfields, and any other UI elements that already have their own tap handlers, so that I can close the popup without hijacking the behaviors of those tap handlers?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var popup: UIView!
    var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.backgroundColor = .white
        textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textfield.placeholder = "some text"
        view.addSubview(textfield)
        
        let button1 = UIButton()
        button1.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button1)
        
        let button2 = UIButton()
        button2.setTitle("Show Popup", for: .normal)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(popupButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button2)
        
        label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .yellow
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textfield.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            textfield.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 160),
            textfield.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 299),
            textfield.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            button1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textfield.bottomAnchor, constant: 40),
            button1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button1.bottomAnchor, constant: 40),
            button2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            //label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button2.bottomAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -260),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        
        textfield.delegate = self
        let viewTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
        viewTapGesture.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        popup?.isHidden = true
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        label.text = "Button tapped!"
    }
    
    @objc func popupButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        if popup == nil {
            popup = UIView()
            popup.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.9175537825, blue: 0.79708004, alpha: 1)
            popup.layer.borderWidth = 1
            popup.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            popup.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(popup)
            
            let stackview = UIStackView()
            stackview.axis = .vertical
            stackview.alignment = .fill
            stackview.distribution = .fillEqually
            stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            popup.addSubview(stackview)
            
            for i in 1...5 {
                let button = UIButton()
                button.setTitle("Selection \(i)", for: .normal)
                button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
                button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(popupItemTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                stackview.addArrangedSubview(button)
            }
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                stackview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popup.topAnchor),
                stackview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popup.leadingAnchor),
                stackview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popup.trailingAnchor),
                stackview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popup.bottomAnchor),
                popup.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor),
                popup.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor),
            ])
        } else {
            popup.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    
    @objc func popupItemTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        label.text = "\(button.currentTitle!) tapped!"
        popup.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        label.text = "You typed:   \(textField.text!)"
        return true
    }

}
```

Here's what it looks like in action. Note that the popup closes when you tap inside it to make a selection. It also closes when you tap outside it, but NOT when you tap in the textfield or tap on "Button". I want the popup to close when you tap anywhere outside it, even inside the textfield or "Button". And if you close it by tapping inside the textfield or on "Button", they should continue to respond as usual.

[image: Tap gesture issue demo]

Comment: "a view which pops up (like a tooltip) when a textfield is tapped inside it"  Where do you have it in code?  Nobody even knows where it comes from and what class you are using to show it.

Comment: @ElTomato I edited my question by including code and demo.

Comment: Hint: `removeFromSuperview()`.

Comment: @ElTomato Sorry, I don't follow. I am not having trouble removing the popup. Actually I'm just hiding it. My question is how to detect tapping anywhere outside the popup including textfields, buttons, etc. so that I can then hide the popup.

Comment: I see.  Sorry about that.  Try adding a gesture to the text field, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling around, I finally found a way to close/hide the popup any time and anywhere the tap occurs and still let whatever UI element anywhere on the screen (including the popup itself) that got the tap do its thing. If the tap is **inside** the popup, the popup selection is made and the popup closes. If the tap is anywhere **outside** the popup on the parent view, the popup closes. If the tap is made on any other UI element on the screen, even if there were a thousand of them on the screen, the popup also closes but the UI element still responds to the tap as usual.

We need to set up the UITapGestureRecognizer, but instead of having a #selector function, we let `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)` do the work, so we set `action: nil`.

```
// Setup TapGestureRecognizer. The ACTION PARAMETER IS NIL since we do not need a
// selector function. We'll let gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:) do the work.
// But we MUST at least register the gesture recognizer's delegate with the view!
let viewTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
viewTapGesture.delegate = self
view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapGesture)
```

and

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if !popup.isHidden {
        popup.isHidden = true
    }
    return false
}
```

Here's the full (revised) code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var popup: UIView!
    var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.backgroundColor = .white
        textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textfield.placeholder = "some text"
        view.addSubview(textfield)
        
        let button1 = UIButton()
        button1.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button1)
        
        let button2 = UIButton()
        button2.setTitle("Show Popup", for: .normal)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(popupButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button2)
        
        label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .yellow
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textfield.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            textfield.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 160),
            textfield.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 299),
            textfield.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            button1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textfield.bottomAnchor, constant: 40),
            button1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button1.bottomAnchor, constant: 40),
            button2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -260),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        
        popup = UIView()
        popup.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.9175537825, blue: 0.79708004, alpha: 1)
        popup.layer.borderWidth = 1
        popup.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        popup.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        popup.isHidden = true
        view.addSubview(popup)

        let stackview = UIStackView()
        stackview.axis = .vertical
        stackview.alignment = .fill
        stackview.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        popup.addSubview(stackview)

        for i in 1...5 {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setTitle("Selection \(i)", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(popupItemTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            stackview.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popup.topAnchor),
            stackview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popup.leadingAnchor),
            stackview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popup.trailingAnchor),
            stackview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popup.bottomAnchor),
            popup.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button2.topAnchor),
            popup.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button2.leadingAnchor),
        ])
        
        textfield.delegate = self
        
        // Setup TapGestureRecognizer. The ACTION PARAMETER IS NIL since we do not need a
        // selector function. We'll let gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:) do the work.
        // But we MUST at least register the gesture recognizer's delegate with the view!
        let viewTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
        viewTapGesture.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapGesture)

    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        label.text = "Button tapped!"
    }
    
    @objc func popupButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        popup.isHidden = false
    }
    
    @objc func popupItemTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        label.text = "\(button.currentTitle!) tapped!"
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        label.text = "You typed:   \(textField.text!)"
        return true
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if !popup.isHidden {
            popup.isHidden = true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

[image: Problem fixed]

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer. This lets you tap outside of pop window. I tested and it works.

1. Add this to your viewDidLoad.

   ```
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        let pop = YourPopup()
   ```
2. Make popup visible after doing something.
3. add the following method:

   @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
   pop.removeFromSuperview()
   }

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is it that you were trying to solve? I don't have s problem removing my popup. My problem is how to detect tapping OUTSIDE the popup including tapping on textfields, buttons, etc. so that I can then close/hide the popup. Please reread the entire question and watch the attached "video".

Comment: I got it. My solution works if you tap anywhere inside :)

Comment: I use something like this to catch tapping outside, but it requires making certain control active. So by analogy I would create a view under popup for the whole screen and make it clickable.  @IBAction func menuButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) { 
       if (isPopupPresented == false) {
             //show popup
                    isPopupPresented = true
                }
        } else {
            isPopupPresented = false
            pop.animateOut()
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just have to add the following:

```
    @objc func buttonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        popup?.isHidden = true 
        label.text = "Button tapped!"
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        popup?.isHidden = true
    }
```

And if there are hypothetically hundreds of textfields and buttons (and other UI elements that have user interaction enabled) in the parent view, I'd have to do the same for each of them. I was hoping for a more generic, elegant solution.